# Cover all 'weighted' points by the smallest set of ranges: is this still a Set Cover problem?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

There is a linear mono-dimensional space ranging from 0 to 100.
In this space exist several points:

```
2.34
14.5
15.3
39.02
54.55
55.67
89.11
91.1
```

Each of these points can be moved along the space by +/-1 unit which we call ranges, like:

2.34 can be placed from 1.34 till 3.34

14.5 can be placed from 13.5 till 15.5

15.3 can be placed from 14.3 till 16.3

... and so on.

If we want to find the smallest sub-collection of segments that cover all the points, this represent a Set Cover problem, that can be solved by a greedy algorithm.
In R I would do something like this

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppGreedySetCover)

#my points collection
Points = c(2.34, 14.5, 15.3, 39.02, 54.55, 55.67, 89.11, 91.1)

#ranges in which points can exists
rangesMIN <- unlist(lapply(Points, function(x) seq(x-1, (x + 0.0001 - x %% 0.0001), by = 0.0001)))
rangesMAX <- rangesMIN + 2

#segments
Segs <- data.table(segments = paste0(rangesMIN, "_", rangesMAX),
                   element = rep(Points, unlist(lapply(Points, function(z) length(unlist(lapply(z, function(x) seq(x-1, (x + 0.0001 - x %% 0.0001), by = 0.0001))))))))


unique(greedySetCover(Segs, F)$segments)
```

which gives:

```
[1] "1.34_3.34"   "14.3_16.3"   "38.02_40.02" "53.55_55.55" "54.67_56.67" "88.11_90.11" "90.1_92.1"
```

All these segments contain the points, fine.
Now, if each point is associated with a 'weight', e.g.

```
2.34 (152)
14.5 (1568)
15.3 (99)
...
```

and I want to find the smallest sub-collection of segments that cover all the points, avoiding points with too different weights (max 2 fold difference) to be present in the same covering segment, is this still a set cover problem?

Comment: I don't think this is the right community to post this question in, since it is a programming question. Maybe [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) will be of more help to you?

Comment: I am not looking for a 'way' to solve the problem. I am more interested to figure out if this is a sort of set cover problem or it is something else, and if it something else hopefully someone has found a solution :).
To the best of my knowledge this does not seems to be similar to any covering/packing-problem...